# How to warn using nagios if privvmpages value exceeds threshold for an application

Tags: 12.04, java, nagios3, openvz, jvm

It would be a great help If someone could help me to achieve this.

> I've rented a VPS with 20GM RAM, but privvmpages maximum limit is 5GB.
>   I have nexus, hudson, puppet, glassfish cluster with one instance, and
>   other 3 java applications running since all these are Java based, In
>   my understanding, privvmpages look for jvm memory as a whole and not
>   jvm memory of individual applications.
>
> And I have configured nagios to monitor some of my applications and
>   its working. Now the complicated part is, I want a service in nagios
>   that alert me when the jvm memory limit as a whole exceeds privvmpages
>   maximum limit.

Is there a service available ? or is this possible in the first place ?

I googled but couldn't find anything

**UPDATE 1:**
 Found some useful info, actually I was wrong in my original post. My understanding was, privvmpages always allocate memory till it reaches the maximum limit. But

> applications are guaranteed to be able to allocate additional memory
>   so long as the amount of memory accounted as privvmpages (see the
>   auxiliary prarameters) does not exceed the configured barrier of the
>   vmguarpages parameter. Above the barrier, additional memory allocation
>   is not guaranteed and may fail in case of overall memory shortage.

Comment: Please review http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95615/cross-posting-etiquette

Comment: can I delete from stackoverflow.com, cos I have been asked to put this question in askubuntu ?

Comment: Since the question is exactly the same, I don't see why not, I would however recommend [edit]ing anything you've tried or seen from the comments there into the question here so we don't cover the same ground here.

Comment: Okay Elder, I already deleted it... sorry

Comment: You might find this interesting: http://wiki.vpslink.com/Memory_Utilization_Script

Comment: Yes, I posted this as comment in my last link :) to get suggestion from others :)

Comment: I think "Shell Script 2" will do the trick. not sure...will have to try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading many posts, I don't think we can find privvmpage size of individual application. rather we can do this

```
#!/bin/bash
bean=`cat /proc/user_beancounters`
guar=`echo "$bean" | grep vmguar | awk '{ print $4;}'`
priv=`echo "$bean" | grep privvm | awk '{ print $2;}'`
let totl=guar/256
let used=priv/256
let free=totl-used
let per=used*100/totl
echo "VPS Memory:"
echo "  total: $totl mb   used: $used mb ($per%)   free: $free mb"
```

Configure this in nagios and compare the threshold values of used/free to alert warnings from nagios

**History behind this**

cat /proc/user_beancounters

First column tells you your current usage, second column tells max usage, third column tells barrier, fourth column tells limit, final column tells you how many times your VPS has failed in a limit.

To convert pages to MB, divide by 256.